# jQuery pop up - ask for variable before loading page

Tags: php, jquery, variables, popup

I need a jQuery popup to ask the user for some required data before loading the same page it's on.

The data entered will become a php variable that I'll use to query a mysql table and pre-populate some form fields.

Any advice?

Thanks!!

Comment: I've tried looking for a solution...

Answer (score 0):

you can make an AJAX call to the PHP and load it to div that you want. For the ajax calls you can use jquery it really makes you job easy.

eg:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'getitems.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#manage_inventory').html(data);
        //alert('Load was performed.');
     }
    });
```

like in the example it is calling getitems.php and getting the list and loading it into #manage_inventory. The data being returned can be XMl or other type which can be parsed and be used according to your needs.

Comment: Well, I just used a lightbox to post to a 'check' page and sent a GET variable back and some isset statements..

Thanks for everyone's help :)

Comment: I'll post the code later, as I'm new so I have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question

Answer (score 0):

Your solution could be as simple as using a `prompt()` box in javascript and then passing the  information via ajax

```
var stuff = prompt('Gimme Stuff');
$.ajax({
    url: 'dostuff.php',
    data: 'stuff=' + stuff,
    success: function(data) {
            //process stuff
     }
    });
```